# Функция которая за 1 вызов обновит разбиение суммы на кол-во ячеек с ограничением. с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, перебор

Дочитайте до конца.

Нужно разложить сумму `s` на `m` ячеек всевозможными способами. При этом есть ограничение на `m[i]` ячейку (нельзя в `i` ячейку записать число больше, чем указано в `m[i]`).

То есть если бы просили разложить `s = 12` на `4` ячейки, то это выглядело так:

```
12  0  0  0,
11  1  0  0,
11  0  1  0,
11  0  0  1,
10  2  0  0,
...
 0  0  0 12.
```

Но есть усложнение с ограничением.Так же нужно написать функцию, которая при одном запуске обновляет вариант разложения.

**Постановка задачи на примере**:
На вход функции подается сумма `double s = 12`, ограничение на ячейки `QVector<double> m = {6,4,8,2}` (в первой ячейке число не больше 6, во второй не больше 4 и тд), шаг переброса `double step = 1` и корректное разбиение суммы `QVector<double> variant = {6, 2, 2, 2}`. При одном вызове функции, она должна обновить variant  на следующий подходящий вариант, в итоге получим `variant = {6, 1, 5, 0}`.

**Пояснение:** Если установить правило, что при создании варианта мы пытаемся в первую ячейку записать всевозможно максимальное число, во вторую аналогично при этом учитывая правила, то все возможные варианты для примера выглядели так:

```
6 4 2 0,
6 4 1 1,
6 4 0 2,
6 3 3 0,
6 3 2 1,
6 3 1 2,
6 2 4 0,
6 2 3 1,
6 2 2 2,  <---
6 1 5 0,  --->
6 1 4 1,
...
0 2 8 2.
больше вариантов нет.
```

Помогите написать такую функцию. Возможно она будет рекурсивной.
Идея для нее:

- Если всего 2 ячейки а1 и b1, то она пытается перебросить шаг step из а1 в b1 : (a1 b1)
- Если больше ячеек, то переброс шага step из а2 в b2, где b2 = (a1 b1).
- Если получится написать ее рекурсивной, то можно ли при дохождении последнего числа и замены выходить из рекурсии больше ничего не делая. Поможет ли проверка на признак `int stopEndNumber == 1`?

Если функция не может выдать следующий вариант она должна изменить признак генерации (перебора) варианта `int stopGeneration == 1`.

Требования к функции

- желательно реализовать шаг переброса из одной ячейки в другую `step`. Если `step=2`, то перекидывай из одной ячейки в другую по двойке. Это сократит кол-во вариантов, и тем самым время программы.
- Функция должна принимать и  работать на прямую с указателями. Так повышается скорость программы.
- Функция должна обновить вариант. Не нужно делать функцию, которая будет перебирать варианты, сохраняя их в вектор. Не забивать память.
- Функция будет использоваться **важно** очень много раз. При этом нужно **зафиксировать изменение** и обработать его далее (генерация числовых таблиц).

Различные ситуации.

- если ничего не заполнено (нет `variant`), то нужно сначала его создать. Допустим создадим вариант, где слева будут располагаться на сколько возможно максимальные числа. Для этого вызовем функцию создания варианта. Если ее можно улучшить, сделайте это.

```
void FirstVariant (QVector<double>* vector, QVector<double> m, double sum, int i_okyda)
{
    for(int i = i_okyda; i < vector->size(); i++)
    {
        if (sum <= m[i])
        {
           (*vector)[i] = sum;
           for(int j = i+1; j < (*vector).size(); j++)
           {
               (*vector)[j] = 0;
               return;
           }
        }
        else
        {
            (*vector)[i] = m[i];
            sum-=(*vector)[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Далее пойдет цикл

```
пвевдокод
for (;можно генерировать вариант?;)
{
вызов функции, которая обновит вариант
// проработай его, сравни и тд
}
```

- если случайно уже будут заполнены цифры в варианте, то их трогать не нужно. Можно посчитать какой суммы не хватает и передать вектор, который указывает на не заполненные по моему мнению ячейки (я знаю, что именно не заполнено).
- Думаю общие случаи рассмотрела и 2 функций будет достаточно. Одна создает вариант, другая обновит его.

---

**Дополнение к ответу пользователя @Stanislav Volodarskiy**

---

Здравствуйте, спасибо. Я пытаюсь понять логику и как применять эти функции.

**Возможно ли добавить шаг переброса числа из одной ячейки в другую?**
Эти функции будут нужны для генераций больших таблиц.(Несколько строк, которые нужно перебирать друг относительно друга).
Будут всевозможные переборы и будет очень много строк, столбцов, даже не сильно большая сумма создаст очень много вариантов. Возможно ли сделать шаг, который перебрасывает не только по 1, а с заданным шагом.

```
Те сумма 8. Ограничение {4, 7, 6} шаг 2 (перебрасывай двойки)
4 4 0
4 2 2
4 0 4
2 6 0
2 4 2 и тд
```

Шаг задастся в коде, будет переменная. Допустим `step=5` перебрасывай из одной ячейки в другую `5`.

Это сократит множество вариантов. Можно сделать большой шаг, и программа быстрее выдаст нужные таблицы, но, если не получилось, уменьши шаг и программа подольше поработает… не получилось еще уменьши и жди дольше.

Comment: `перебрасывай двойки` -  считайте для вдвое меньших значений и при выводе умножайте на 2

Comment: А как перебирать строки таблиц? Функция перебирает одну строку без признака, как сделать так, чтобы после перебора строки, перейти на следующую строку изменить ее 1 раз и снова перебирать старую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first` строит первую комбинацию `board`. Сумма распределяется слева направо: в первую ячейку помещается столько разрешает параметр `shape`, остаток размещается правее. Когда сумма обнулилась, хвост заполняется нулями.

`first` возвращает истину, если сумму можно разместить в массиве. Если сумма слишком велика и не может быть размещена, вернётся ложь.

`next` двигается по `board` справа налево и ищет свободное место (`space`) в ячейках. Если место есть и текущая ячейка не пуста (`*p > 0`), то текущая ячейка уменьшается на единицу а оставшаяся сумма распределяется вызовом `first` по хвосту массива. Если изменение удалось, возвращается истина, иначе ложь.

Пример использования:

```
if (first(shape, board, sum)) {
    do {
        // использование board
    } while (next(shape, board));
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename It1, typename It2>
bool first(It1 shape_b, It2 board_b, It2 board_e, int sum) {
    It1 q = shape_b;
    for (It2 p = board_b; p != board_e; ++p) {
        int term = std::min(sum, *q);
        *p = term;
        sum -= term;
        ++q;
    }
    return sum == 0;
}

template<typename It1, typename It2>
bool next(It1 shape_b, It2 board_b, It2 board_e) {
    if (board_b == board_e) {
        return false;
    }

    It2 p = board_e - 1;
    It1 q = shape_b + std::distance(board_b, p);

    int sum = 0;
    bool space = false;
    for (; ; ) {
        if (space && *p > 0) {
            --*p;
            return first(q + 1, p + 1, board_e, sum + 1);
        }
        sum += *p;
        if (*p < *q) {
            space = true;
        }
        if (p == board_b) {
            break;
        }
        --p;
        --q;
    }
    return false;
}
    
bool first(const std::vector<int> &shape, std::vector<int> &board, int sum) {
    return first(shape.begin(), board.begin(), board.end(), sum);
}

bool next(const std::vector<int> &shape, std::vector<int> &board) {
    return next(shape.begin(), board.begin(), board.end());
}

int main() {
    int sum;
    std::cin >> sum;
    std::vector<int> shape;
    int v;
    while (std::cin >> v) {
        shape.push_back(v);
    }
    std::vector<int> board(shape.size());

    if (first(shape, board, sum)) {
        do {
            for (auto p = board.begin(); p != board.end(); ++p) {
                std::cout << ' ' << *p;
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        } while (next(shape, board));
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp 
>
> $ echo 12 6 4 8 2 | ./a.out
>  6 4 2 0
>  6 4 1 1
>  6 4 0 2
>  6 3 3 0
>  6 3 2 1
> .
> .
> .
>  0 4 7 1
>  0 4 6 2
>  0 3 8 1
>  0 3 7 2
>  0 2 8 2
> ```

Comment: Здравствуйте, вы сделали очень интересные функции, но у меня появились вопросы как их применять. Добавила текст выше.